# Iteratively Expanding Solutions in Multiple Variables

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, series-expansion

I've been working on a physics problem which requires finding the limiting behavior of variables as another variable goes to either zero or infinity. What I have is relations between 16 independent variables (a0, a1, a2,..., a15). I want to go through the relations between these variables in a for loop and expand each in terms of one of the others. On the first iteration in my For loop I want to set a0 = 1, then expand a1 through a15 in terms of a1. Then I want to do the same but expand everything in terms of a2, then a3, then a10 and then a11. After this, I want to set a1=1 and expand everything else in terms of a0, then a2, then a3, then a10 and then a11. Next I want to repeat these steps but setting a2=1, then setting a3=1, then a10=1 and then a11=1.

I've pasted my current code and the error messages I'm getting below. My first problem I've identified is that S[[i]] = 1 does not actually set the variable to 1 like I would like it to, it just places the value 1 in the list S. What I wanted this line of code to do was to on the first iteration, set a0=1 then on the second set a1=1, etc.

Some notes on the loops:

the variable i in the first for loop represents going through the 6 variables that mathematica says are explicitly non-zero in "relations". On each loop, one of these variables will be set to 1.

the variable j in the second for loop represents running through each of the remaining non-zero variables and expanding in terms of that variable.

the variable l in the third for loop represents taking each of the three distinct roots for a2, which are given in "relations".

the variable k in the fourth for loop represents going through all of the 16 variables and expanding each of them in terms of a_j.

Let me know if my explanation is clear or if you need more information, and thanks in advance for any help!

Here's what the variable "relations[[8]]" is bound to (for this specific problem I only care about the 8th part of relations).

```
relations[[8]]

a1 != 0 
&& (a2 == Root[a0^2 a1^2 + a0^2 #1^2 + a1 #1^3 &, 1] || 
   a2 == Root[a0^2 a1^2 + a0^2 #1^2 + a1 #1^3 &, 2] || 
   a2 == Root[a0^2 a1^2 + a0^2 #1^2 + a1 #1^3 &, 3]) 
&& a0 != 0 
&& 
 a3 == (a2 (a0^2 + a1 a2))/(a0 a1) 
&& a4 == (a1 a2)/a0 
&& 
 a5 == a2^2/a0 
&& a6 == 0 && a7 == (a2 a3)/a0 
&& 
 a8 == (-a1 a3 + a2 a4)/a0 
&& 
 a9 == (-a2 a3 + a1 a4 + a2 a5 + a4 a7 + a5 a8)/a0 
&& a2 != 0 
&& 
 a10 == -((a1 a3)/a2) 
&& a11 == (a1^2 - a0 a3 + a3 a4)/a0 
&& 
 a12 == (a3 a5)/a0 
&& a3 != 0 
&& a13 == (a11 a5)/a3 
&& a11 != 0 && 
 a14 == (a12 a13)/a11 
&& a10 != 0 
&& 
 a15 == (a11^2 - 4 a4^2 + 4 a3 a5)/a10
```

And here's the code I currently have.

```
Clear[S, Z, vars, MatOfExpansions, expansions]
NonZeroVars = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a10, a11};
vars = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, 
   a14, a15};
xyz = {x, y, z};
MatOfExpansions = {};

(*Run through all the non-zero elements, setting each to one on its \
given iteration.*)
For[i = 1, i < 7, i++, 
 S = {a0, a1, a2, a3, a10, a11};
 S[[i]] = 1; 
 
 (*Run through all the non-zero elements that are also not equal to \
one (this is what the If statement below takes care of). We will then \
take the limit at the end as each of these variables goes to either \
zero or infinity.*)
 For[j = 1, j < 7, j++, 
  Z = vars - S[[i]] - S[[j]]; 
  
  (*We only want the instances where j and i are not the same, 
  because j=
  i would mean we are setting one variable equal to one and then \
expanding in powers of that variable (doesn't make any sense)*)
  
  If[j != i, 
   
   (*l runs through the three different solutions that we get from \
Reduce. This corresponds to the three different solutions to the \
third order polynomial (the star equation)*)
   
   For[l = 1, l < 4, l++,
     expansions = {};
     rules = {};
     
     (*Run through all the different variables, 
     expanding each in powers of a_j*)
     For[k = 1, k < 17 , k++,
      
      (*Append to expansions the expansion of a_k in powers of a_j*)
 
           AppendTo[expansions, 
        {vars[[k]], 
        Series[vars[[k]] /. {ToRules[
             And @@ Select[
               relations[[8]] /. x_ || y_ || z_ -> xyz[[l]], 
               Head[#] === Equal || Head[#] === Or &]]} /. 
          rules, {S[[j]], 0, 10}]}];
      
      (*Append to rules the rule a_k \[Rule] 
      expansion of a_kx in powers of a_j*)
      
      AppendTo[
       rules, {vars[[k]] -> 
         Series[vars[[k]] /. {ToRules[
               And @@ Select[
                 relations[[8]] /. x_ || y_ || z_ -> xyz[[l]], 
                 Head[#] === Equal || Head[#] === Or &]]} /. 
            rules /. {{x_}} -> x, {S[[j]], 0, 10}]}];
      
      ];
     
     (*Add to MatOfExpansions all of the expansions in terms of a_j \
along with some identifying information*)
     
     AppendTo[
      MatOfExpansions, {StringForm[ "`` = 1", NonZeroVars[[1]]], 
       StringForm["In terms of: `` around 0",  NonZeroVars[[j]]], 
       expansions}]];
   
   (*Finishing the If statement*)
   , Continue[]]
  
  (*Closing out all of the For loops*)
  ]]
```

I've also tried using AsymptoticSolve on relations[[8]] to try to do all of this in a much more concise way, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Rewrite your relation in terms of a[0], a[1], a[2], ... , a[15], and your variables become `Array[a,16,0]`. It's then easier to iterate over them that way, and easier to do things like `a[i]->1`

Comment: I can only understand your first paragraph, but your code wanders off into expanding polynomials and becomes very confusing after the second for loop. Couldn't you just do `nonZeros = SortBy[Cases[rel, Unequal[var_, 0] :> var, Infinity], First];
vars = Array[a, 16, 0];
results = Table[Simplify[rel /. nz -> 1], {nz, nonZeros}];` assuming you've rewritten your relation like this:  https://pastebin.com/BFJqJr71

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's very helpful. The code you gave in the second comment works to give me my relations with one of the variables set to 1, but now I want to do a series expansion. So for example, the first expansion I want is a[0] = 1, a[1] left alone and then a[2], a[3], ... , a[15] expanded in terms of a[1].

Comment: Forgot to tag you in my previous comment @flinty